# Pearson Correlation of the Principal Curvatures

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, correlation

Consider the set of all possible smooth 3D surface patches. Now, let's say that I draw $K$ random points from that set, where each point is parametrized by its principal curvatures $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$. So, I have $K$ points, where each is embedded as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I stack all of them into a matrix $A$ of size $K \times 2$. By calculating the Pearson correlation coefficient of the two columns of $A$, I can estimate the correlation between the two principal curvatures.

Intuitively, I would expect the correlation to approach $0$ as $K \to \infty$, since both $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ can take any value, regardless of the other. In other words, in my intuition, picking a random point from the family of smooth manifolds is equivalent (at least for me) to drawing two random real numbers, one after the other, which represent the principal curvatures.

However, I cannot show it through numeric experimentation. In my experiments, where I follow the exact same process as described above for $K > 10^6$, I get that the correlation is around $0.5$, which is counter-intuitive, at least for me.

Is it possible to prove that the correlation should be $0$? Or is my intuition wrong?

Comment: What is the measure you're putting on "the set of all possible smooth surface patches"? And how do you get a single pair of numbers as the curvature of a patch, when those curvatures vary across the patch?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis What do you mean by measures? I just say that they are smooth to any necessary degree.
I do not get a single pair of numbers per patch. When I draw a point, I first draw some random surface patch, and then, I draw a random point from that patch, and that point is represented by its principal curvatures (that is at least how I practically run my experiments).

Comment: Theoretically, I would like to rephrase my question as just drawing random points with a local smooth neighborhood, so I will be able to claim that the principal curvatures are defined. You can basically ignore the need for surface patches. In essence, I just draw $K$ random points which are parametrized by their principal curvatures. The need for patches is just for practical experimentation.

Comment: OK, sampling a random point from the random patch makes sense, that answers my second question - thanks for clarifying :). But my first question stands: whenever you're "drawing randomly", you're sampling using some measure (= probability distribution). The answer to your question will depend on the distribution you put on the set of all surface patches, and I don't see a particularly obvious choice. In other words, I think the result of your simulation will depend very much on the method you're using to generate your surface patches, so we need to know that method.

Comment: Your second comment doesn't make much sense to me - if your random points are not sampled from surface patches, how does it make sense to talk about their principal curvatures?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks for replaying back. My points are indeed sampled from surface patches, my second answer was trying to put the question in a more "slim" context. Regarding how I generate the patches - I tried various methods, here are a few examples: applying Gaussian smoothing to random noise, interpolating RBF functions, using Perlin and Simplex noise, and inverse Fourier transform. They all give nice and smooth patches. I guess that it also depends on how I sample those patches afterward.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I believe that it is actually the smoothness of the patches that inject some bias into the correlation calculation. Since the patches are quite smooth, nearby points will have similar principal curvatures... so I get some correlation from there.

Comment: Here is an example for a smooth patch that I generate: (this one is based on RBF interpolation)
https://youtu.be/Fs0o7c8W0no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to propose a clear and unequivocal definition of the parametrization and the measure you want to use to define the random patches. Nevertheless, I think it is possible to shed some light on the question and maybe also on your intuition by proposing a simple approach to randomisation.

Let us use [Monge patches](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MongePatch.html) around the pount $(u,v)=(0,0)$ and let's specialize to quadratic surfaces, and choose coordinates such that they are orthogonal in $(0,0)$. To make these random in a well-defined fashion, write:
$$ h(u,v) = \frac X 2 u^2 + \frac Y 2 v^2$$
where $X, Y$ are random variables with finite first and second moments. Each random instance of $X,Y$ will provide you with a random patch of graph $(u,v,h(u,v))$ around $(0,0).$ The principal curvatures are then two random variables. Their correlation is
$$ \text{Corr}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2) = \frac{\text{Cov}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(\kappa_1)\text{Var}(\kappa_2)}}.$$

To go further, one needs to fix the measure, i.e. define the joint distribution of $(X,Y).$ There is basically no right or wrong distribution, which one to use is just a matter of choice. Of course, to obtain closed formulas, one needs simple assumptions. Following the preferences of the OP those will be:

1. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
2. $X$ and $Y$ are uniform on the interval $[0,L]$ for an $L>0.$

Using the formulas cited above one can conclude that Gauss and mean curvature at the point $(0,0)$ are
$$ K = XY\quad\text{ and }\quad H=\frac 1 2 (X+Y).$$

Furthermore, the [principal curvatures](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalCurvatures.html) can be expressed in terms of $H$ and $K$ as
$$ \kappa_1=H + \sqrt{H^2-K}\quad\text{ and }\quad \kappa_2=H - \sqrt{H^2-K}.$$

Using those formulas conclude:
$$ \sqrt{H^2-K} = \frac{1}{2} \lvert X - Y \rvert$$
$$ \kappa_1 = H + \sqrt{H^2-K} = \max\{X,Y\}$$
$$ \kappa_2 = H - \sqrt{H^2-K} = \min\{X,Y\}.$$

Now plug those into the definition of covariance:
\begin{align} 
\text{Cov}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2) 
&=\mathbb{E}[\kappa_1 \kappa_2] - \mathbb{E}[\kappa_1] \mathbb{E}[\kappa_2]\\ 
& = \mathbb{E}[K] - \big( \mathbb{E}[H]^2 - \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{H^2 - K}]^2 \big)\\
&=   \mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{2} \lvert X - Y \rvert\Big]^2 \geq 0.
\end{align}
For the last line use $\mathbb{E}[K] = \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\frac 1 2 (X+Y)]^2 = \mathbb{E}[H]^2$ due to independence assumption. This shows already the problem with the OP's intuition: The principal curvatures will always have non-negative correlation. Furthermore, since they are max and mins of a common pair of variables, they will be independent only in trivial cases!

Finally obtain by straightforward integration:
$$ \text{Cov}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{2} \lvert X - Y \rvert\Big]^2 = \frac 1 4 (\frac 1 3 L)^2 = \frac 1 {36} L^2$$
and
$$ \text{Var}[\kappa_1] = \text{Var}[\kappa_2] = \frac 1 {18} L^2$$
to arrive ultimately at
$$ \text{Corr}(\kappa_1,\kappa_2) = \frac{\frac 1 {36} L^2}{\frac 1{18}L^2}=\frac 1 2.$$
The result seems to be in full agreement with the observations  of the OP.

As a quick quality check, verify the results by simulation:

```
n = 1e6

f_sample = function(L){ 
  X = L * runif(n)
  Y = L * runif(n)
  
  K = X * Y
  H = (X + Y) / 2
  
  kappa_1 = H + sqrt(H^2-K)
  kappa_2 = H - sqrt(H^2-K)
  
  cor(kappa_1, kappa_2)
}

tt = sapply(c(1,10,100,1000), f_sample)
print(tt)
[1] 0.4991383 0.5012970 0.5004247 0.5005081
```

As a final remark, observe that the distributions are not invariant under change of coordinates. It may be more aligned with the geometric spirit to specify distributions for the invariants instead, and then work backwards to coordinates or to properties of the patch. But this seems to me much harder.

Comment: Thanks. That is interesting, let me also experiment with it first :-)

Comment: I do not like this example. Unless $Z=0$ you are always going to have a saddle surface, which means that $K<0$. The coefficients of the linear terms are not so relevant, but I think you should have $Ux^2+Vy^2$ or (not particularly needed) $Ux^2+2Vxy+Wy^2$.

Comment: @gg I get different results actually. I have experimented with the quadratic case, and I get a correlation of ~0.08. The correlation seems to drop even further as I draw more and more points (but quite slowly, which is expected).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the definition of $h$.

Comment: I'm interested to see what @gipouf finds when experimenting with this :)

Comment: @gipouf In the example only the point corresponding to $(u,v)=(0,0)$ is sampled (and the formulas are valid only for this point!). May this be different from the sampling approach you are using?

Comment: @gg I will experiment with it today (I will replicate your example). However, I think that it is wrong to sample the coefficients from the normal distribution, can't it implicitly inject some bias toward a specific patch shape? If the normal distribution is centered around $0$, then you're biased toward a planar patch (correct me if I'm wrong). IMHO you should sample your coefficients using the uniform distribution.

Comment: You can sample any which way you want, there is no sampling police calling you out. You will get different results, but they all are legitimate. This is why everyone tells you, you need to decide on a sampling measure. There is no general "correct" measure.

Comment: @gg I understand that different sampling methods will yield different results, but eventually, there is also an objective answer. If we could analytically calculate the correlation, we would get a single number. Now, I believe that if you sample uniformly, you will get a result that is closer to the analytic one.

Comment: There is an objective answer, given the measure. There is no "objective" measure, i.e. joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z).$

Comment: @gg Why there isn't? The principal curvatures are eventually a local geometric property. What if I could generate all possible quadratic patches and calculate the correlation of their principal curvatures? (at $\left(0,0\right)$) It should exist in the "limit" sense.

Comment: No! Principal curvatures are a geometric property for each instance of your random variables. But once you want to calculate correlations between different instances, you need a measure! There is no way around this additional(!) choice. And there is no canonical measure. In particular there is no uniform distribution over $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: @gg I know that you cannot sample uniformly from $\mathbb{R}^3$, but you also don't need to IMHO. You can just sample from the unit cube. I believe that you won't see much difference in the result as you continuously expand your cubic sampling domain. Anyway, thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: @gipouf See my edits for uniform distributions. You are right, there is no difference when extending the interval.