# Pearson Correlation of the Principal Curvatures and their Derivatives

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, correlation

In continuation to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722103/pearson-correlation-of-the-principal-curvatures), consider that I want to extend the calculation, and also calculate and numerically evaluate the correlation between the principal curvatures and their derivatives w.r.t. the principal directions. So, for example, I would like to calculate the correlation between $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_{1,1}$, where $\kappa_{1,1}$ is the derivative of $\kappa_1$ w.r.t. the first principal direction.
So, consider that I follow the same structure as given in the answer to the question referenced above, and use a quadratic Monge patch:
$$ h\left(u,v\right) = \frac{X}{2}u^2 + \frac{Y}{2}v^2$$
Where $X$ and $Y$ are two uniformly distributed random variables.

In this case, the second fundamental form matrix is a diagonal matrix, so if I understand correctly, at $\left(0,0\right)$ the principal directions should be aligned with the coordinate directions of the parametrization plane. Does it mean that in this case, the derivatives of $h$ w.r.t. $u$ and $v$ are equivalent to the derivatives of $h$ w.r.t. the principal directions $d_1$ and $d_2$?

If that's true, then since $\kappa_1 = H + \sqrt{H^2 - K}$, and $H$ and $K$ [can be expressed](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MongePatch.html) as functions of $h$ and its derivatives, then I can differentiate $\kappa_1$ w.r.t. to $u$ in order to find $\kappa_{1,1}$, and finally, evaluate $\kappa_{1,1}$ at $\left(0,0\right)$ to express it as a function $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yes, this should work as described. One detail, though: Generally, you need to distinguish between the covariant and the (standard) directional [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Christoffel_symbols,_Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations,_and_the_Theorema_Egregium). You have not stated what kind of derivative you want to compute.

Comment: @gg I want to differentiate along a vector on the UV parametrization plane, along which an infinitesimal movement corresponds to an infinitesimal movement along a principal direction on the surface's tangent plane at (0,0). I believe that in our special case, the tangent plane aligns with the UV parametrization plane.

Comment: Yes, but even more pertinent: I just realized, you want to differentiate a scalar, not a vector field. The distinction only applies if you want to differentiate vector fields, so you may safely ignore my prior comment.

Comment: @gg Right, thanks. I actually did exactly what I described using a symbolic differentiation package, and figured out, which is actually not surprising IMHO, that in our special case, the derivatives of $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ along $u$ and $v$ (which are aligned with the principal directions in our case) at $\left(0,0\right)$ are identically $0$. So, I realized that what I really want to do, is to be able to differentiate $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ along the principal directions also in the case where they are not aligned with $u$ and $v$. That seems to be much more challenging.